# Как сделать так, чтобы прозрачность не передевалась всем элементам в блоке, а только блоку

Tags: html, css

Допустим , так

```css
.block{
opacity:.5;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">  
<div class="content">
<text> Любой текст или фото.</text>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/d/d9/%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA_%28%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%29.jpg/220px-%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA_%28%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%29.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: что Вы хотите чтобы было полупрозрачное, зеленый бэкграунд?

Comment: ДА, именно зеленый , а другое пусть не меняется

Comment: В целом, Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите прозрачность только для беграунда...

```css
.block{
background:rgba(2,127,60,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">  
<div class="content">
<text> Любой текст или фото.</text>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/d/d9/%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA_%28%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%29.jpg/220px-%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA_%28%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%29.jpg" alt="#">
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Идеально, благодарю